# Is "Zuccarin"/"White Mullberry" effective for weight loss?

Tags: natural-remedies, weight-loss, sugar

An ad for a supplement called "Zuccarin" in our local paper included a variety of claims:

> "The slimming effect of stable blood sugar levels:
>
> "A recent italian study of Zuccarin showned the impressive weight loss
>   results of blocking carbohydrates. The diet group on Zuccarin lost
>   substantially more weight than the placebo group and their waist
>   shrunk more as well."
>
> "Zuccarin...mullberry leaf supplementation...the tablets naturally
>   block carbohydrates from being digested into simple sugar. This helps
>   your waistline and your blood sugar levels."
>
> "Test yourself: Sugar problem:
>
> - Lack of energy
> - Difficulty losing weight
> - Sugar cravings
> - Feeling tired and irritated
>
> These are some clues that your blood sugar may be unstable or too
>   high. Try Zuccarin..."

Impressively, they cite:

> Da Villa, G., et al. "White mulberry supplementation as adjuvant
>   treatment of obesity." Journal of biological regulators and
>   homeostatic agents 28.1 (2014): 141-145.

I couldn't access the full text, but I found [this snippet](http://www.dldjournalonline.com/article/S1590-8658(14)60368-6/pdf), which sounds pretty impressive - I'm not qualified to know how good their methodology was. There appear to be several studies on similar subjects.

Are the claims posed accurate - is blood sugar a mechanism for the symptoms described, and can "White Mullberry" produce the effects claimed?

Comment: It'a pretty obscure journal https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Biological_Regulators_and_Homeostatic_Agents IF of 2. Even if the research was summarized correctly...

Comment: [WebMD does mention](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-1250-white%20mulberry.aspx) that "There are some chemicals in white mulberry that work in a similar way to some medicines used for type 2 diabetes." So it's perhaps not implausible.

Comment: And Wikipedia names the substances "Moracin M, steppogenin-4′-O-β-D-glucoside and mulberroside A were isolated from the root bark of Morus alba L. and all produced hypoglycemic effects". The ref for that being https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19545615 which has about 79 citations in GS so it's perhaps not complete bullshit although I'm unfamiliar with [the journal](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/fitoterapia) in which this was published as well. It's about par with the other one on IF, so likewise pretty obscure research.

Comment: On the other hand: https://sciencebasedpharmacy.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/mulberry-for-weight-loss/

Comment: Also http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0144861716302727 was cited by https://www.cbi.eu/market-information/natural-ingredients-health-products/mulberries/

Comment: Finally there's a review https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29287458 it has full page on anti-diabetic activity but only a paragraph or two on anti-obesity, mostly suing the paper I mentioned in the comment right before this one. The latter paper is in a somewhat better rated journal: https://www.journals.elsevier.com/food-chemistry IF 4+

Comment: @Fizz whew, you've done some research! That science basedpharmacy link seems to summarize things pretty well, I think...